# Пошуки "у глибину" і "у ширину" чи "вглиб" і "вшир"

Tags: вибір-слова

На вікіпедії статті про алгоритми пошуку на графах називаються

- [Пошук у глибину](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA_%D1%83_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)
- [Пошук у ширину](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA_%D1%83_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Які є причини не використовувати коротші назви *пошук вглиб* і *пошук вшир*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не бачу ніяких причин не застосовувати «пошук углиб (вглиб)» і «пошук ушир (вшир)».

«Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко) 2010 дає:

> **[search](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=search&main_only=on&dicts=2)** = [sɜ:tʃ] **1.** по́шук, шука́ння || шука́ти // **~ out** знайти́ **2.** перебира́ння/перебра́ння *(варіантів)* || перебира́ти/перебра́ти *(варіанти)*
>
> - <…>
> - **breadth-first ~** = [по́шук уши́р](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80&dicts=2&highlight=on)
> - <…>
> - **depth-first ~** = [по́шук угли́б](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA+%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1&dicts=2&highlight=on)
> - <…>

Чому такі варіанти не застосували у Вікіпедії, мабуть, доречніше спитати у відповідних авторів статей.